# What is the URL of the result?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

[This answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5173/submitting-jobs-to-ibm-devices-without-python) states that:

> Once it is submitted, your job will be in queue. You will have to request by GET this job ID to get the answer from the backend.
>   The GET URL is: https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/api/Jobs/execution_id.
>   You will get another JSON answer (put it in a `r_json` variable). If it has the `qasms` item, see if `r_json['qasms'][0]` has a `result` item and you will get the result of the submission.

But when I download it with python, I got a HTML but not JSON.
When I open this URL in Chrome, I just enter https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/

The question I meet is there are too many circuit need to run (19200 circuit). But One task can take 64 circuit. (When I try 96 circuit, it fail) So I have to create 300 tasks. Download these result one by one is not easy, so I want a URL.
If someone can tell me how to download 300 results quickly or how to run more circuit in **One** task. It also really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: what code did you use to "download it with python"?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a task?

Comment: I believe the circuit limit in a single job is 75. Also, would obtaining the results through Qiskit using `job.result()` and then storing the results object returned not suffice? You could send a job, save the information from results that you need, send the next job, etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone. At first I want to use Crawler technology to download result, but I use selenium download result automatically at end. It is not good for me to use job.result() download result. Because I send 50 jobs to the IBMQ at one time, and I have to wait until all jobs were finished before downloading the results. So I save all jobs' id and download results by selenium.