# IBM Quantum API for Java Developers

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

As far as I know, IBM Quantum provides two types of APIs: one for Qiskit, and the other for third-party uses (**API for developers**).

In [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/ibm-quantum-experience-api-without-qiskit), there are several arguments about using the **API for developers**, there are even useful links to some sources.

But now IBM has changed the interface of its platform, and I can't figure out where to get the **API token for developers** (while the API token for Qiskit is in the most prominent place).

I would also like to see an **example of using the API** in action **in Java**. Example of a program that sends a schema to IBM Quantum and gets the result.

In total, I have two questions:

1. Where is the API token for developers?
2. Example of using the API in Java.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question,

> Where is the API token for developers?

The API token can be copied from your [account details](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/account) page:

[image: IBM Quantum API Token]

For the second question,

> Example of using the API in Java.

[IBM Quantum API](https://api.quantum-computing.ibm.com/v2/explorer/) is a RESTful API. It can be consumed the same way as any RESTful API using a REST client. And when it comes to Java, there are many options to choose from to build a REST client. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5024571) from StackOverflow contains some good options. However, if you are building your solution using a Java Framework, most probably you will find it supports consuming REST APIs. It should be your first option.

Anyway, the following is a simple example using Spring's RestTemplate. The code does not follow the best practices (e.g., no error handling). It is for demonstration only:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String baseUrl = "https://api.quantum-computing.ibm.com/v2";

// Login
URI loginUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl)
    .path("/users/loginWithToken")
    .buildAndExpand()
    .toUri();

LoginPayload payload = new LoginPayload();
payload.setApiToken("*********");
HttpEntity<LoginPayload> request = new HttpEntity<>(payload);
JsonNode loginResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(loginUrl, request, JsonNode.class);
String accessToken = loginResponse.get("id").asText();

// Get Providers Information
URI providersInfoUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl)
    .path("/Network")
    .queryParam("access_token", accessToken)
    .buildAndExpand()
    .toUri();

// Parse the response to get list of devices
JsonNode response = restTemplate.getForObject(providersInfoUrl, JsonNode.class);
for(JsonNode node : response) {
    if(node.get("name").asText().equals("ibm-q")) {
        JsonNode devices = node.get("groups").get("open").get("projects").get("main").get("devices");
        for(JsonNode device : devices) {
            System.out.println(device.get("name"));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, if you plan to support checking the job status in your solution then you will need to support WebSocket also.